# C++ - ifstream not liking relative paths

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have been having trouble with opening files with ifstream

if I do:

```
ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:/Users/build/windows/Debug/map1.xml");
```

it works fine, but if I do a relative path (the executable is in Debug/)

```
ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("map1.xml");
```

It will not find the file.  Any help?  Am I missing something silly?

Comment: Where are you running the application from?

Comment: There's a good chance that the application's working directory is not the one that map1.xml is in.

Comment: running it in visual studio, but I have the same result if I navigate to the Debug/ folder and double click on the executable

Comment: VS2013 is now respecting the idea of relative paths when using ifstream and debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your IDE changes your program's working directory when launching it. Try putting `map1.xml` into `c:\users\build\windows`

Comment: sigh, I guess the executable was not being updated when I always stopped in the debugger or something, now if I just build and run it from the debug directory (by double clicking it in windows explorer) it all works :/  Any setting I can change to make visual studio run it from the debug/ directory during debugging etc?

Comment: nvm, found it.  Shame I can't automate that change via cmake since that's what I'm using to generate the VS project file :/

Comment: @will If you start VS from that directory, won't it be the working directory when your program executes? If so, create a batch file (or link?) and set the current directory to `C:/Users/build/windows/Debug`